# SUMIF Range in Range

Tags: excel, sumifs

I'm trying to sum only if a value from a collection is in a set list of values.

I've tried using a `SUMIF`but it keeps returning 0.

**Given:**

[image: ValueList]

*and*

[image: CheckValues]

*and*

[image: ValuesToSum]

**I've Tried:**

```
=SUM(SUMIF(M7:M10,X2:X4,H7:H10))
```

But it's returning 0 each time. How can I modify this to correctly SUMIF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or just use SUMPRODUCT()

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(H:H,M:M,X2:X4))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add 3 sumifs:

```
=SUMIF(M7:M10,X2,H7:H10))+SUMIF(M7:M10,X3,H7:H10))+SUMIF(M7:M10,X4,H7:H10))
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem for me with this solution is that I'll need to negate row by row so Range M **not in** X

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array formula, enter:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(M7:M10,X2:X4,H7:H10))
```

and Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (or COMMAND+RETURN on the Mac) to enter the formula

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/275165/when-to-use-a-sum-if-array-formula

Comment: You are not the same as you link.  This will not work as is.  Your link uses `SUM(IF())` not `SUMIF()`

Comment: If you wrap it in SUM: `SUM(SUMIF(M7:M10,X2:X4,H7:H10))` and Array enter it will work.

Comment: See Example 3: SUMIF() Worksheet Function

Comment: When I do CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER nothing happens to the cell

Comment: It's while you're editing the formula... with the cursor in the editing box hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: Try it out with their data, it does not work.  It returns 9 instead of 16.

Comment: Sorry - you're right of course... it 'worked for me' as all of the sample data is 'CA'

Comment: We are here to learn and improve.  I was hoping that you were correct and I could save some typing in the future.