# SUMIF NOT Range is in Range

Tags: excel

I'm trying to sum only if a value from a collection is **not** in a set list of values.

**Given:**

[image: ValuesList]

*and*

[image: CheckValues]

*and*

[image: ValuesToSum]

**I've Tried:**

```
=SUM(SUMIF(M7:M10,"<>" & X2:X4,H7:H10))
```

I should Expect to see 10,000 (for row 8) But it keeps returning a nonsensical value (120,000).. How can I modify this to correctly SUMIF **not** in the range.

Comment: FYI the reason you get `120000` is that the `SUMIF` part of the formula return an array of each of the `<>` tests ie `{10000, 55000, 55000}`.  Sum of which is `120000`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Array/CSE formula:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF($X$2:$X$4,M7:M10)=0, H7:H10, 0))
```

Just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter that in so it gets the squirrelly brackets around it.

Or you can hit it with sumproduct and some sneaky boolean logic to avoid the array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(COUNTIF($X$2:$X$4,M7:M10))*H7:H10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take one of the answers in your [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302293/sumif-range-in-range) and substract it from:

```
SUM(H7:H10)
```

That is:

```
=SUM(H7:H10)-SUM(SUMIF(M7:M10,X2:X4,H7:H10))
```

Entered as an Array Formula